# imacros: Scrape URLs using xpath

Tags: javascript, xpath, imacros

Here is my code, which scrapes Google search:

```
SET !LOOP 1
TAG XPATH=".//*[@id='rso']/div/div[{{!LOOP}}]/div/h3/a" EXTRACT=HREF
TAG XPATH=".//*[@id='rso']/div/div[{{!LOOP}}]/div/h3/a" EXTRACT=TXT
SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=google_search.txt
```

How do I fix it? Maybe this whole xpath is wrong.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In many google search result pages you will get multiple element with this xpath.

```
.//*[@id='rso']/div/div[1]/div/h3/a
```

or

```
.//*[@id='rso']/div/div[2]/div/h3/a
```

But iMacros doesn't support this kind of xpath. I have got a better solution for you. Please try the following code.

```
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
SET !LOOP 1

TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=H3 ATTR=CLASS:r EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:{{!EXTRACT}} EXTRACT=HREF

SAVEAS TYPE=EXTRACT FOLDER=* FILE=google_search.csv
```

This code worked fine for me.